# Do Until issues in VB6

Tags: loops, transactions, vb6, iteration, recordset

I've encountered some issues in VB6. 2 of the issues appear to be getting caused by me using a `Do Until` loop.

These issues comes from the below code

```
Dim strAccount As String

On Error GoTo PayBalance_Err

If dtaEmployees.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If MsgBox("Are you sure you would like to pay all outstanding balances? This change cannot be undone.", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
Else

    Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass

    dtaEmployees.Recordset.MoveFirst

    If dtaEmployees.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Do Until dtaEmployees.Recordset.EOF

           dbsPeriod.BeginTrans

           strAccount = dtaEmployees.Recordset.Fields(1)

           If GotBatch = False Then
               Batch_Number = Get_Batch_Number()
               Batch_Line = 0
               GotBatch = True
           End If

           Batch_Line = Batch_Line + 1

           Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
           sql = "SELECT * FROM [Ledger Transactions] WHERE [Account_Code] = '" & strAccount & "' AND [Outstanding] > 0"
           Set rs = dbsPeriod.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)

           sql = "UPDATE [Ledger] SET [Sales_Balance] = 0, [Date_Last_Cash_S] = " & Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & " WHERE Account_Code = '" & strAccount & "'"
           dbsPeriod.Execute sql

           sql = "UPDATE [Ledger Transactions] SET [Outstanding] = 0 WHERE [Account_Code] = '" & strAccount & "'"
           dbsPeriod.Execute sql

           Dim GoodsValue, VAT, TotalValue As Currency
           GoodsValue = dtaEmployees.Recordset.Fields(3) / 1.2
           VAT = GoodsValue / 5
           TotalValue = dtaEmployees.Recordset.Fields(3)

           Dim pPeriod, pYear As String
           pPeriod = Mid(DB_Period_Name$, Len(DB_Period_Name$) - 7, 2)
           pYear = Mid(DB_Period_Name$, Len(DB_Period_Name$) - 5, 2)

           sql = "INSERT INTO [Ledger Transactions]([Batch_Number], [Batch_Line], [Account_Code], [Reference], [Description], [Goods_Value], " & _
                 "[VAT_Value], [Total_Value], [Outstanding], [Document_Date], [Period], [Year], [Type], [Sort_Order]) VALUES(" & Batch_Number & ", " & _
                 Batch_Line & ", '" & strAccount & "', 'PAYROLL', '" & txtDescription.Text & "', " & GoodsValue & ", " & VAT & ", " & TotalValue & _
                  ", 0, " & Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ", '" & pPeriod & "', '" & pYear & "', 'P', 1)"

           dbsPeriod.Execute sql

           rs.MoveFirst

           Dim TotalPayment As Currency
           TotalPayment = 0

           Do Until rs.EOF
              TotalPayment = TotalPayment + rs.Fields(10)

              rs.MoveNext
           Loop

           rs.MoveFirst

           Do Until rs.EOF
              GoodsValue = rs.Fields(8)
              VAT = rs.Fields(9)

              sql = "INSERT INTO [Allocations]([Payment], [Account_Code], [Sales_Or_Purchase], [Payment_Batch_Number], [Payment_Batch_Line], " & _
                    "[Payment_Reference], [Payment_Date], [Payment_Value], [Invoice_Batch_Number], [Invoice_Batch_Line], [Invoice_Type], [Invoice_Date], " & _
                    "[Invoice_Goods], [Invoice_VAT], [Date_Allocated], [Who_Allocated], [Goods_Allocated], [Discount], [VAT_Allocated]) " & _
                    "VALUES(True, '" & strAccount & "', False, " & Batch_Number & ", " & Batch_Line & ", 'PAYROLL', " & _
                    Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ", " & rs.Fields(10) & ", " & Batch_Number & ", " & Batch_Line & ", 'I', " & _
                    Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ", " & GoodsValue & ", " & VAT & ", " & Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ", '" & User_ID$ & "', " & _
                    GoodsValue & ", 0, " & VAT & ")"

              dbsPeriod.Execute sql

              sql = "INSERT INTO [Audit Header]([Batch_Number], [Batch_Line], [Account_Code], [Sales_Or_Purchase], [Type], [Reference], " & _
                    "[Description], [Goods_Value], [VAT_Value], [Total_Value], [Document_Date], [VAT_Percentage_1], [Goods_1], [VAT_1], " & _
                    "[Post_Date], [Who_Posted], [SOPS_Provisional_Due]) " & _
                   "VALUES(" & Batch_Number & ", " & Batch_Line & ", '" & strAccount & "', False, 'I', 'PAYROLL', '" & txtDescription.Text & "', " & _
                   GoodsValue & ", " & VAT & ", " & rs.Fields(10) & ", " & Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ", 20, " & GoodsValue & ", " & VAT & _
                   ", " & Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ", '" & User_ID$ & "', " & Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ")"

              dbsPeriod.Execute sql

              rs.MoveNext
           Loop

           rs.MoveFirst

           sql = "INSERT INTO [Allocations]([Payment], [Account_Code], [Sales_Or_Purchase], [Payment_Batch_Number], [Payment_Batch_Line], " & _
                "[Payment_Reference], [Payment_Date], [Payment_Value], [Invoice_Batch_Number], [Invoice_Batch_Line], [Invoice_Type], [Invoice_Date], " & _
                "[Invoice_Goods], [Invoice_VAT], [Date_Allocated], [Who_Allocated], [Goods_Allocated], [Discount], [VAT_Allocated]) " & _
               "VALUES(True, '" & strAccount & "', False, " & Batch_Number & ", " & Batch_Line & ", 'PAYROLL', " & _
               Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ", " & rs.Fields(10) & ", " & Batch_Number & ", " & Batch_Line & ", 'P', " & _
               Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ", " & GoodsValue & ", " & VAT & ", " & Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ", '" & User_ID$ & "', " & _
                GoodsValue & ", 0, " & VAT & ")"

             dbsPeriod.Execute sql

             sql = "INSERT INTO [Audit Header]([Batch_Number], [Batch_Line], [Account_Code], [Sales_Or_Purchase], [Type], [Reference], " & _
                   "[Goods_Value], [Total_Value], [Document_Date], " & _
                  "[Post_Date], [Who_Posted], [SOPS_Provisional_Due]) VALUES(" & Batch_Number & ", " & Batch_Line & ", '" & strAccount & _
                  "', False, 'P', 'Payment', " & rs.Fields(10) & ", " & rs.Fields(10) & ", " & _
                  Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ", " & Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ", '" & User_ID$ & "', " & _
                 Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & ")"

             dbsPeriod.Execute sql

             sql = "INSERT INTO [Audit Lines]([Batch_Number], [Batch_Line], [Batch_Line_Item], [Account_Code], [Sales_Or_Purchase], " & _
                  "[Nominal_Code], [Reference], [Description], [Goods_Value], [VAT_Value])" & _
                " VALUES(" & Batch_Number & ", " & Batch_Line & ", 1, '" & strAccount & "', False, '" & Cmb_Code.Text & "'" & _
                 ", 'PAYROLL', '" & txtDescription.Text & "', " & GoodsValue & ", " & VAT & ")"

             dbsPeriod.Execute sql

             dbsPeriod.CommitTrans

             dtaEmployees.Recordset.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
End If

Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault

MsgBox "Payment(s) complete!", vbOKOnly, "Success"

dtaEmployees.Refresh

grdEmployees.Redraw = True

Exit Sub

PayBalance_Err:

   Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault

   MsgBox "An error has occurred. " & err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
   dbsPeriod.Rollback
```

In my test data, `dtaEmployees.Recordset.RecordCount` is 2. The first iteration of the loop works fine and the data inserts correctly using the transaction.

However, there are a couple of issues with the second iteration of the loop.

The first being that the transaction isn't being set. Each SQL statement is executing individually, and in my error trap I call `dbsPeriod.Rollback` and there is an error saying

> You tried to commit or rollback a transaction without first using BeginTrans

But, I'm setting the transaction in the 3rd line of the code?

The second issue occurs just before this. I get the following message

> An error has occurred. Object invalid or no longer set.

when the code reaches the line `rs.MoveFirst`. The `rs` record set is being set at the top of the loop again, so I'm not sure why it's saying it's not been? `rs` is not used between these two lines so I'm not sure why it's going wrong? There is definitely data matching that query because I've run it in Access itself.

If anyone is able to help me fix even one of the issues I'd appreciate it a lot, I've been stumped for hours on this.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, the transaction is begun and committed inside the loop. Instead of this:

```
If dtaEmployees.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then    
    Do Until dtaEmployees.Recordset.EOF
        dbsPeriod.BeginTrans

        '... 

        dbsPeriod.CommitTrans
        dtaEmployees.RecordSet.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

you may want this:

```
If dtaEmployees.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
    dbsPeriod.BeginTrans
    Do Until dtaEmployees.Recordset.EOF

        '... 

        dtaEmployees.RecordSet.MoveNext
    Loop
    dbsPeriod.CommitTrans
End If
```

Aside the from that, the ROLLBACK code referred to in the question is not included with the sample, so that's all I can suggest.

Additionally, I strongly suspect this entire thing could be reduced to a **single call to the database**, completely eliminating the need for the loop.

For the 2nd problem, the code that was skipped over is important. Either something there is breaking the recordset, or the set is failing in the first place. If you're using `On Error Resume Next`, you should **stop that**. It's hiding your errors, making debugging difficult.

Finally, the way the SQL string is built is crazy-vulnerable to injection attacks. I hope you are **very** sure of your data source, building SQL strings in that bad way. Learn how to use the `ADO.Parameter` object.

Comment: I need the transaction inside the loop, as the code is going over each employee in the system and updating their purchase history. Each customer may have multiple purchases, which is why I want one transaction per customer, as that way if an update for one purchase fails, it only fails for that employee, and not the entire process - does that make sense?

Comment: I've added the full subroutine to the question in case it helps to understand and resolve the issues more easily.

Comment: It makes some sense. I'd still try to reduce total round-trips to the database. Did you know you can train multiple SQL commands together in a single `.Execute` call? : `sql = "UPDATE x SET y = 1;UPDATE a SET b = 2;"` Do this and things will run faster, plus you get an implicit transaction (so much less code).

Comment: So, `sql = ` and then attach all of my statements separated by a `;`, with a unique ID (e.g. `UPDATE a; UPDATE b;`) for each?

Comment: The `a` and `b` are just placeholders so you could see something resembling two complete queries in the same sql command.

Comment: A quick scan also shows MsgBox and MousePointer code in that function. It's good practice to move all of the DB code throughout the application into a separate module that never directly touches the UI. This current function would call methods in the new Module

Comment: So an example would be `sql = "UPDATE [Ledger] SET [Sales_Balance] = 0 WHERE [Account_Code] = 'myAccount'; UPDATE [Ledger Transactions] SET [Outstanding] = 0 WHERE [Account_Code] = 'myAccount';`

I can then add each query in the same way and execute them all with one `.Execute`?

Comment: Exactly. Even better if the `'myAccount'` value is a parameter variable `@myAccount` you set via an `ADO.Parameter` object.

Comment: You can also put T-SQL statements like `If`, `DECLARE`, and `SET` into the command string. And, while I'm at it, `current_timestamp` or `Getdate()` instead of `Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy")` Some developers find it easier to put the big SQL statements into a config file they can read in at runtime, rather than deal with a huge ugly string in the source. This also means you can edit the SQL without a re-compile.

Comment: I'm using `MS-Access`, so it would need to be `Date()`, rather than `GetDate()`

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it won't fix the issue with your transactions (are you sure you only have one database open?), the `RecordSet` issue will likely be resolved by adding `rs.Close` at the end of each loop.